# Port configuration for spark driver to subscribe on mesos master

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, mesos

I have a spark driver which is connected to my Mesos master. Driver is listening on a particular port to my Mesos master for resource offers

> Received SUBSCRIBE call for framework 'Simple kafka application' at scheduler-901ab680-7098-4cb0-ab27-4b293285a2b6@xxx.xx.xx.xxx:57033

I would like to configure this port as I will need to whitelist this port on my machines. 
I am not able to figure out which conf will this be. I have configured spark.driver.port and broadcast port but I am pretty sure these are not used in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

To use custom port for communication with Mesos you need to specify [`LIBPROCESS_PORT`](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/1.2.0/docs/configuration.md#libprocess-options) environment variable with port number that should be used. By default it's unset or set to `0` and this cause random port.

```
export LIBPROCESS_PORT=<PORT>
```